# How to store GeoSMS into a PostGIS table?

Tags: postgis, geosms

I wish to import GeoSMS messages into a PostGIS table.

Any suggestions or helpful API to be used?

Comment: what did you try, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to store whole message as text in one column and than write simple triggered function after insert which will create geometry from text using regexp search